Custom Policy for Synapse Analytics Private Endpoint Non-Compliant
I have created custom policy for adding private endpoints on Synapse Analytics Workspace. See Script below.
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces"
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "DeployIfNotExists",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
          "existenceScope": "subscription",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].privateLinkServiceId",
                    "equals": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{synapseWorkspaceName}"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
                    "equals": "SqlOnDemand"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].privateLinkServiceId",
                    "equals": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{synapseWorkspaceName}"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
                    "equals": "Sql"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].privateLinkServiceId",
                    "equals": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{synapseWorkspaceName}"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
                    "equals": "dev"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },

But the above policy is Non-Compliant. See image below
I believe there were a mismatch fields on the script, your help is truly appreciated. Thank you in advance geez!

Are you getting any error with your code?

Hi @VenkatV Thank you for responding, no error with the code but when checking Policy - Compliance it says Non-Compliant.

Do you want to check non-complaint resources that do not have private endpoint enabled, or enable private endpoint if it does not exist?

The effect is DeployIfNotExists, then the result after deployment is Compliant.

Are you still facing the issue? @Romeo

Hi @Jahnavi, the issue resolved by changing "allof" to "anyof", thank you for all supporters here.

I will post an answer in detailed way for the others in the community. Please check. @Romeo

As mentioned by @Romeo, replacing   allOf with anyOf should resolve the issue here. Posting our discussion as an answer for the community benefit.
The functionality of allOf operator in a policy rule is to make sure that all the given conditions under a specific block should be true. If it satisfies, then only it does evaluate and triggers effect trigger. Whereas the anyOf operator evaluates to true if there is a one included condition is true.
Refer MSDoc on explaining multiple policy rules with sample definitions.
Modified existenceCondition block is given below:
Using anyOf rather than allOf checks if any one of the private endpoint configurations such as SqlOnDemand, Sql, or dev exists in the synapse, then the policy evaluates it as compliant one.
 "existenceCondition": {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].privateLinkServiceId",
                  "equals": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/', parameters('synapseWorkspaceName'))]"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
                  "equals": "SqlOnDemand"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].privateLinkServiceId",
                  "equals": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/', parameters('synapseWorkspaceName'))]"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
                  "equals": "Sql"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].privateLinkServiceId",
                  "equals": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/', parameters('synapseWorkspaceName'))]"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
                  "equals": "dev"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
      },

Definition created successfully:

Reference MSDoc for exploring all the logical operators available in Azure policy definition structure.
